# Public-Private key pair ssh authorization for another login

Tags: ssh, debian, remote-access, public-key

Currently to connect to my server via ssh I am using

```
ssh domain.com -l root
```

I am authenticated with public-private key pair.

My Mac username is different from root, so I need to provide -l key.

Is there any option no to enter this key, so simply:

```
ssh domain.com
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in `~/.ssh/config`

```
    Host domain
    Hostname domain.com
    User root
```

Then you can simply do `ssh domain`.